# SQL - Why does this think i am using NULL id's

Tags: sql

```
declare @id as int
declare @group_id as varchar
declare @user as varchar
declare @sp as varchar
declare @date as datetime

insert into TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP values
(@id, @group_id, @user, @sp, @date)
select @id = nm.ID_NUM, @group_id = twg.GROUP_ID, @user = 'asalgado', @sp = 'Testing script', 
@date = GETDATE()
from NAME_MASTER nm
left outer join TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP twgm on twgm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join TW_GROUP twg on twg.GROUP_ID = twgm.GROUP_ID
left outer join STUDENT_MASTER sm on sm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join CANDIDACY c on c.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
where sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'G' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'GR' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 
'W'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WR'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WD'
```

Trying to push users into the table using their ID's but not sure what i'm doing wrong exactly, i keep getting an error stating ID cannot be NULL which makes sense because i don't want them to be null

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax

```
insert into TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP
select nm.ID_NUM, twg.GROUP_ID, 'asalgado', 'Testing script', GETDATE()
from NAME_MASTER nm
left outer join TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP twgm on twgm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join TW_GROUP twg on twg.GROUP_ID = twgm.GROUP_ID
left outer join STUDENT_MASTER sm on sm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join CANDIDACY c on c.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
where sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'G' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'GR' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 
'W'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WR'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WD'
```

or

```
select @id = nm.ID_NUM, @group_id = twg.GROUP_ID, @user = 'asalgado', @sp = 'Testing script', 
@date = GETDATE()
from NAME_MASTER nm
left outer join TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP twgm on twgm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join TW_GROUP twg on twg.GROUP_ID = twgm.GROUP_ID
left outer join STUDENT_MASTER sm on sm.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
left outer join CANDIDACY c on c.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
where sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'G' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'GR' OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 
'W'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WR'OR sm.CURRENT_CLASS_CDE = 'WD'

insert into TW_GRP_MEMBERSHIP values
(@id, @group_id, @user, @sp, @date)
```